Extract Variable Name for Unset Script
I have a .env file that contains information, to include environment variables. For example:
# comment
<mini script>

export NAME="John Doe"
export LOCATION="US"
export TZ_LOCAL="NY"

When ran, I am able to have these environment variables; however, when done, a script runs to unset the environment variables.
This is the snippet that does such:
unset $(grep 'export' env | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "=" }; { print $1 }' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = " " }; { print $2 }')

This seems a bit much. Is there a simpler way to get the variable name after export and stop at the equal sign?
This snippet works, but seems like there should be a much simpler way than my snippet with multiple pipes.

General practice is to source variables into a subshell that exits when you no longer want those variables -- that way no explicit unset operation is ever needed; the variables just go away when the process they were added into ends.

For example, instead of export foo=bar; ./myprog; unset foo, you can just run (export foo=bar; exec ./myprog) -- at the close of the parens foo goes away, and because exec itself consumes the subshell there's no performance hit. (Of course, that particular example is so degenerate it could even be replaced with foo=bar ./myprog all as one line).

To give more detail as to why this is being done this way, I use virtual environments with pyenv.  Unlike with conda, I have to also use autoenv which sources the .env file within the project directory.  There is also a .env.leave file that gets ran when exiting the project directory.  The .env file contains a script that automatically activates the pyenv activate command along with sourcing the environment variables for the virtual environment.  When leaving the directory the .env.leave deactivates the virtual env and unsets the variables.

The tools I've seen for the purpose, like direnv, handle unloading for you automatically. I'd generally suggest using tools that already have polished solutions rather than trying to roll something yourself.

I ended up going with direnv. Thank you!

Use space and = as input field separator:
unset $(awk -F '[ =]' '/^export .*=/{print $2}' env)

